# How to Download file from Google drive in WPF - installed application

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am developing WPF application and in this I am implementing Google Drive API with Upload and Download functionality. The Upload is working fine but I am facing problem in downloading the document. I looked at the code in Google document at https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads

```
 public static System.IO.Stream DownloadFile(IAuthenticator authenticator, File file) 
 {
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file.DownloadUrl)) 
   {
     try {
       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(file.DownloadUrl));
       authenticator.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);
       HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
       if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) 
       {
          return response.GetResponseStream();
       }
       else
       {
          Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + response.StatusDescription);
          return null;
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
      return null;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    return null;
  }
```

}

But according to this document
"https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/Authentication/IAuthenticator.cs?r=e6585033994bfb3a24d4c140db834cb14b9738b2"
it is showing that "IAuthenticator is not supported any more" and thus the above code is not working.

I tried of using UserCredential but it is throwing "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.".

So please provide code for the same in WPF application or how can I download any type of file from Google drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation you need to download new Google.Apis.Auth nuget package. After that follow these steps

- Visit the Google APIs console
- If this is your first time, click "Create project..."
- Otherwise, click on the drop down under the "Google APIs" logo at the top left, and    click "Create..." under "Other projects"
- Click on "API Access", and then on "Create an OAuth 2.0 Client ID...".
- Enter a product name and click "Next".
- Select "Installed application" and click "Create client ID".
- In the newly created "Client ID for installed applications", copy the client ID and    client secrets into the AdSenseSample.cs file.
- Activate the Drive API for your project.

Reference [Google APIs Client Library for .NET](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Downloads)

After these step finished you can download the file with following codes

```
private async Task Run()
    {
        GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "Drive.Sample";
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("client_secrets.json",
            System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None);
        }

        // Create the service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
        });

        await UploadFileAsync(service);

        // uploaded succeeded
        Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" was uploaded successfully", uploadedFile.Title);
        await DownloadFile(service, uploadedFile.DownloadUrl);
        await DeleteFile(service, uploadedFile);
    }


    private async Task DownloadFile(DriveService service, string url)
    {
        var downloader = new MediaDownloader(service);
        downloader.ChunkSize = DownloadChunkSize;
        // add a delegate for the progress changed event for writing to console on changes
        downloader.ProgressChanged += Download_ProgressChanged;

        // figure out the right file type base on UploadFileName extension
        var lastDot = UploadFileName.LastIndexOf('.');
        var fileName = DownloadDirectoryName + @"\Download" +
            (lastDot != -1 ? "." + UploadFileName.Substring(lastDot + 1) : "");
        using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName,
            System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            var progress = await downloader.DownloadAsync(url, fileStream);
            if (progress.Status == DownloadStatus.Completed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileName + " was downloaded successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Download {0} was interpreted in the middle. Only {1} were downloaded. ",
                    fileName, progress.BytesDownloaded);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can download [sample application](http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.8.2/Generated/ZipFiles/google-api-dotnet-client-1.8.2.samples.zip) for google drive apis.

Comment: Can you please also help me in calculating the value for progress bar from ProgressChanged event. I was trying this:                 void Download_ProgressChanged(IDownloadProgress obj)
        {
            prgrsVal = obj.BytesDownloaded;
        }                                                              here prgrsVal is my property bound to 'Value' property of ProgressBarEdit control of devexpress. For this I want some proper percentage value between 0-100. The obj does not have total bytes of the file to be downloaded,if it has then I can calculate it easily. So please help me.

Comment: @user3771143 You can do something like this;
`var percentage = (prgrsVal / file.size) * 100;`
this give you a value between 0-100